# Pass UIButton event from subview to superview

Tags: ios

I have a UIView like a menubarView with buttons.

I added this menubarView to another view (parentView).

I need to call a method on the parentView on TouchUpInside of menubar button.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(myLocalMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Call My Method" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self addSubview:button];
```

Solution:
In menuBarView I added this code:

```
- (void)myLocalMethod:(UIButton *)button
{
    ParentView *parent = (ParentView *)self.superview;
    [parent myMethod:button];
}
```

Comment: Currently I have the buttons created on the parentView itself. But I want to create another view to have the buttons and place it inside the parent view. I'm not sure how to pass the event, so I haven't done any code for it yet.

Comment: I couldn't format it as 'code'. It just doesn't work.

Comment: In my opinion, how about using delegate or callback block instead of your way? I think dependency between superview and its subviews should be eliminated as much as passible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in **myMethod**

```
[((<SuperViewName>)self.superview) <methodInSuperView>]
```

Replace the placeholders **SuperViewName** and **methodInSuperView** with your names.

Explanation: I am casting the superview to the appropriate superview class and the invoking the required superview method. Make sure the **methodInSuperView** is public (Declare it in interface).

Comment: For my current requirement VikramRao's method worked. I didn't try @drewag's method yet. I updated my question with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to provide callback blocks on the subview:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^onDidTapMyButton1)();
```

Then implement an action (or a target and selector) on the subview that calls this callback:

```
- (IBAction)didTapMyButton1 {
    if (self.onDidTapMyButton1) {
        self.onDidTapMyButton1();
    }
}
```

In your parent view you can then do:

```
mySubView.onDidTapMyButton1 = ^{
    // perform some action
};
```

You can also do this with a single callback for all buttons:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^onDidTapButton)(UIButton *tappedButton);

- (IBAction)didTapButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (self.onDidTapButton) {
        self.onDidTapButton(sender);
    }
}
```